# How do I suppress certain key-sequences in mode keymaps?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm currently experimenting with mediawiki-mode and yasnippet. They both have binding for the TAB key in their respective mode-map. How do I programatically tweak the mediawiki-mode-map so it doesn't re-map TAB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical way of unsetting a keybinding in a map, is to set it to nil.
So:

```
(define-key mediawiki-mode-map (kbd "TAB") nil)
```

Comment: might also want to add a hook that checks when one of the modes is active and disables to TAB key of the other mode (according to which is important to stsquad)